# Divide and conquer on sorted input with Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

For a part of a divide and conquer algorithm, I have the following question where the data structure is not fixed, so *set* is not to be taken literally:

Given a set X sorted wrt. some ordering of elements and subsets A and B together consisting of all elements in X, can sorted versions A' and B' of A and B be constructed in time linear in the number of elements in X ?

At the moment I am doing a standard sort at each recursive step giving the recursion

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n*log n)
```

for the complexity rather than

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n)
```

like in the procedural version, where one can utilize a structure with constant-time lookup on A and B to form A' and B' in linear time.

The added `log n` factor carries over to the overall complexity, giving `O(n* (log n)^2)` instead of 
 `O(n* log n)`.

EDIT:
Perhaps I am understanding the term lookup incorrectly. The creation of A' and B' in linear time is easy to do if membership of A and B can be checked in constant time.

---

I didn't succeed in my attempt at making things clearer by abstracting
away the specifics, so here is the actual problem:

I am implementing the algorithm for the [closest pair problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem). Given a
finite collection P of points in the plane it finds a pair of points
in P with the minimal distance. It works roughly as follows:

If P
has at least 4 points, form  Px and
Py, the points in P sorted by x- and y-coordinate. By
splitting Px form L and R, the left- and right-most
halves of points. Recursively compute the closest pair distance in L and
R, let d be the minimum of the two. Now the minimum distance in P is
either d or the distance from a point in L to a point in R. If the
minimal distance is between points from separate halves, it will appear
between a pair of points lying in the strip of width 2*d centered around
the line x = x0, where x0 is the x-coordinate of
a right-most point in L. It turns out that to find a potential minimal distance pair in
the strip, it is enough to compute for every point in the the strip its 
distance to the seven following points if the strip points are in a
collection sorted by y-coordinate.

It is in the steps with forming the sorted collections to pass into the recursion and sorting the strip points by y-coordinate where I don't see how to, in
Haskell, utilize having sorted P at the beginning of the recursion.

Comment: What Haskell has to do with this?

Comment: I am implementing this in Haskell. In a language where one have access to a constant-time lookup data structure it is trivial to do, so the question exists because of the characteristics of Haskell.

Comment: OK, so what lookup, constant-time or otherwise, has to do with this? A list can be partitioned in two in linear time. If it was sorted, the two halves will stay sorted. Why do you need to sort at each recursive step? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a 'set' data structure that has this property?

Comment: @n.m I am not partitioning a sorted data structure. I have the sorted data structure X and a disjoint union of X (A, B) and am asking if, in Haskell, it is possible to form (A', B') in linear time where A' and B' are sorted versions of A and B. What constant-time lookup has to do with this is that in a language with constant-time lookup for some data structure, doing what I want to do is trivial. Specifically I am implementing the closest pair algorithm for points in the plane.

Comment: @augustss No, not directly. I am asking if what I want to do can be done in Haskell noting that it is not clear how to do it when there is no way of getting constant-time lookup in Haskell.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. It is not clear how do you do this with a constant-time lookup data structure. To me this doesn't look trivial at all. Can you demonstrate how to do it with arrays? Or perhaps you mean hash tables?

Comment: @user847614 But Haskell has constant-time 'lookup' data structures, like arrays.

Comment: Maybe `lookup` is not the correct term ? I mean lookup in the sense of knowing if a given element is element of a given collection. In case you have functionality, you simply "scan" X which is sorted and eg. add an element x to A' if lookup shows it is in A.

Comment: @augustss I should have used "checking for membership" instead of lookup.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Could you give a more precise specification of your problem, for instance by implementing an inefficient version? What does `T(n)` have to do in your question about linear time?

Comment: If your values can be used for indexing (i.e., can be made a member of the Ix class) you can construct the array in O(n) time and then do a scan of the full set in O(n) time using constant time lookup.  You can also use some kind of hashing if implementing Ix is difficult.

Comment: Ugh. I see. You do look up by value, not by index. Your unsorted set is really a set with a O(1) check-membership operation. You can implement it with e.g. a hash table. Well, you can do it in Haskell too. Not very efficiently (google `haskell hash table flying frog`) but an implementation exits.

Comment: Or you can try to use [this](http://gregorycollins.net/posts/2011/06/11/announcing-hashtables) or [this](https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers).

Comment: The hash table in the hashmap package isn't bad at all.  The unordered-containers are slower, but more space efficient.

Comment: Also, if your values can be serialized in some form (or are something appropriate to begin with), tries are constant-time in collection size.

Comment: Like Daniel Wagner said, I would recommend looking at the [partition](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#partition) function and its helper function `select`. Try to figure out how they are working and construct your own short function with type `(a->Bool)->(b->Bool)->[a]->[b]->([a],[b])` and I'm pretty sure it can be done in linear time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am updating my question to maybe make things clearer, but I might have what I need after doing some reading.

Comment: @Heinrich Apfelmus T(n) is the overall complexity of the algorithm. The part in the recursion after 2*T(n/2) is the part stemming from the sorting part of the "merging" step in the algorithm. If I have to do a regular sort at each step in the recursion I get T(n) = 2* T(n/2) + O(n* log n), if I can do it in linear time, I get T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The following function may interest you:

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
partition f xs = (filter f xs, filter (not . f) xs)
```

If you can compute set-membership in constant time, that is, there is a predicate of type `a -> Bool` that runs in constant time, then partition will run in time linear in the length of its input list. Furthermore, `partition` is stable, so that if its input list is sorted, then so are both output lists.

I would also like to point out that the above definition is meant to be give the *semantics* of partition only; the real implementation in GHC only walks its input list once, even if the entire output is forced.

Of course, the real crux of the question is providing a constant-time predicate. The way you phrased the question leaves sets A and B quite unstructured -- you demand that we can handle *any* particular partitioning. In that case, I don't know of any particularly Haskell-y way of doing constant-time lookup in arbitrary sets. However, often these problems are a bit more structured: often, rather than set-membership, you are actually interested in whether some easily-computable property holds or not. In this case, the above is just what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I know very very little about Haskell but here's a shot anyway.

Given that (A+B) == X can;t you just iterate through X (in the sorted order) and add each element to A' or B' if it exists in A or B? Give linear time lookup of element x in the Sets A and B that would be linear.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing in my Java implementation, but I don't see yet how to get the linear time lookup in Haskell.